# Website Page Loader Duration Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, pageload

Im added page load GIF icon  for my bootstrap web site, but i have a small issue , this image loader is very fast loading, i need to make time duration for this loader , Im added `duration` but its not work ,how can i fix it?
Thanks

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
 
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
  
  ;
 });
```

```css
no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 background:url("https://thumb.ibb.co/hqtTTk/Preloader_2.gif" )center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow"); }, 3000);
```